# Formatted reads and implied do

Tags: fortran

In Fortran one has the option to use implied loops. They are usually used for printing and have the following structure.

```
write(*,'(5I6)') (i,i=1,20)

! output 
 1     2     3     4     5
 6     7     8     9    10
11    12    13    14    15
16    17    18    19    20
```

This would allow to write 5 integers of width 6 and when done, go automatically to the next line. Therefore, it is quite useful for formatting.

The question is if this can be done in reverse

```
read(*,'(5I6)') (a(i),i=1,20)
```

This would of course not work, as it is written, because there are only 5 elements per line. Never the less I would like to ask how to flip to the next line in an automatic mode. I am currently counting the number of entries and once 5 is reached, I go to the next line. Another option would be to read the file in a binary scratch file, where no 'new' lines exist. This would not work neatly for me, because I use keywords search with the `index()` function.

Comment: What do you mean by "This would of course not work"?  The main problem is that you haven't an input variable to read in to, but why do you think the input like that fails more widely?

Comment: I was too quick when typing, of course I should read in an array. I edited the question. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Or, if `a` has 20 elements, `read(*,*) a` is highly likely to read 20 elements from a file.  In simple cases there's not much to be gained either from explicit input formats or from implied-do loops.

Comment: This works splendid, the problem was that the values looked like this `1.711111-01-1.411111-01` no space between the negative number and the one before it, also no `E` for the exponential notation. This caused the read to file. I have to figure out how to cure this.

Comment: *the problem was that the values looked like this 1.711111-01-1.411111-01*  I think you've misunderstood the question, which is quite explicitly about reading and writing integers.

Comment: I just used the integers as a simple example, the equivalent would be `111111-222222`. This caused the failure. Anyway, your suggestion is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this if you really need the format for some reason

```
do i = 1, n, 5
  read(*,'(5I6)') a(i:i+4)
end do
```

otherwise the list directed format would work well as suggested by High Performance Mark.

You could write it as an implied do, but sub-arrays are better.

I could even imagine a one liner with a format descriptor including `/`, but why bother?

(too long for a comment)

Comment: The problem was actually due to the wrong format of the input data. Exponential numbers are written in this form `1.711111-01-1.411111-01` and since they appear to be joined together the read failed

Comment: Actually, the other answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

*Format reversion* is the key term here.  It applies to both output and input.

Before going further, the implied-do is largely irrelevant, so I'm going to stick to data transfer statements with whole arrays.  That's true for the first output where it may as well be an array with the values 1 to 20 rather than an implied-do (try it!).  So,

```
read (*,fmt) a
```

is just like

```
read (*,fmt) (a(i),i=1,20)
```

when `a` has those bounds.

For output, the going "automatically to the next line" is part of processing output with format reversion.  Once the format items have been exhausted and there remain more items to write out we go back to the start of the format.  We also move onto the start of the next record.  In this case, that's the start of a new line.  Which gives the output

```
 1     2     3     4     5
 6     7     8     9    10
11    12    13    14    15
16    17    18    19    20
```

After every fifth item of the twenty we start a new line.

Format reversion is the same when reading.  Given

```
read(*,'(5I6)') a
```

five elements of `a` are transferred according to the `5I6` part of the format.  At that point the format item list is exhausted and format reversion occurs.  Back to the start of the format and on to the next record.

To conclude

```
read(*,'(5I6)') a
```

*is* the reverse of

```
write(*,'(5I6)') a
```

Comment: Right, I didn't forget format reversion, but I did forget that the end of record is automatically inserted.