# Opening and reading a file in Fortran

Tags: fortran

```
open(NEWUNIT=fId, file=trim(filename), iostat=ierr, action='READ')                                                                           
    if (ierr /= 0) return
    read(fID,'(A)') dataArray
    close(fId)
```

Does this code read the complete data in a file and save it in an array or it just reads a single line?

Comment: Welcome please supply the details. Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What did you try? did you try to write out the values and if so what were your conclusions?

Comment: The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39999346/3157076) should be helpful, though.

Comment: I'm surprised that no one complained that a complete working example was not provided. The question should include the declaration of dataArray for any sensible answer to be useful. The questioner needs to understand this requirement.

Comment: @johncampbell, MCVEs certainly are useful generally.  However, in this case I don't feel necessary.  We can make sufficient assumptions about everything in the code (`dataArray` a character variable, hopefully an array, for example) that a specific example (particular file, specific lengths, etc.) may actually end up distracting from an otherwise simple and generic question.  With a question "why am I reading only 64 characters?" for example, yes details very much required.  (I did how an earlier comment to the asker looking for specifics, but changed my mind about broadness.)

Comment: As to the question, "read the complete data" the answer is most likely "NO", as it will either read to the dimension of dataArray or report an end of file error. The read should be in a DO loop reading 1 line at a time, testing for an end of file, else reporting the array is not big enough, or in the very unlikely case, the array dimension is the number of lines in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider

```
character(len=10) name(5)
read(*,'(A)') name
```

Having the whole array in the input stamement is treated the same as as specifying the array's elements in order:

```
read(*,'(A)') name(1), name(2), name(3), name(4), name(5)
```

The input statement will attempt to read five values, each according to the edit descriptor `A`.  What happens as a result depends on various things.

*Format reversion* means that when one value is transferred the file is positioned on the next record (line).  So, in the case here assuming the file has at least two lines, the first 10 "characters" of the first line are read and put into `name(1)`.  Then the first 10 "characters" of the second line are read and put into `name(2)`.  And so on for as long as lines remain.

Situations (assuming no errors come about):

- there are as many lines as elements of the array: all lines are read in to the array (but only as much of a line as the character length of the variable);
- there are more lines than there are elements: only the number of lines equal to the number of records are read;
- there are more elements than there are lines: an end-of-file condition occurs and the array `name` becomes undefined.